# ¿Como puedo enviar el resultado que hace mi programa a mi base de datos en phpmyadmind a una tabla igual en php para que se muestren las consultas?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, vscode

tengo un incoveniente con un chatbot que estoy diseñando, el chatbot consta de 3 partes:
1 Chatbot.php: que contiene lo que son los divs de chatbot y ahi mismo el script para crear el ajax que consultara a la base de datos.
2 message.php: contiene la conexion a la base y todos los datos para realizar la consulta y que devuelva la respuesta a la pregunta que ingrese el usuario
3 Style.css: para darle diseño al chatbot.
Mi duda es que quiero que la consulta que haga el usuario desde que empieza a hablar con el chatbot, se muestre en una tabla con con html.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ChatBot Presidencia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style2.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">ChatBot Presidencia</div>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="bot-inbox inbox">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="msg-header">
                    <p>Hola, ¿Como puedo ayudarte?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="typing-field">
            <div class="input-data">
                <input id="data" type="text" placeholder="Type something here.." required>
                <button id="send-btn">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#send-btn").on("click", function(){
                $value = $("#data").val();
                $msg = '<div class="user-inbox inbox"><div class="msg-header"><p>'+ $value +'</p></div></div>';
                $(".form").append($msg);
                $("#data").val('');
                
                // start ajax code
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'message2.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'text='+$value,
                    success: function(result){
                        $replay = '<div class="bot-inbox inbox"><div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div><div class="msg-header"><p>'+ result +'</p></div></div>';
                        $(".form").append($replay);
                        // when chat goes down the scroll bar automatically comes to the bottom
                        $(".form").scrollTop($(".form")[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ese codigo es para el chatbot

```
<?php
// connecting to database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chatbot") or die("Database Error");



// getting user message through ajax
$getMesg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['text']);

//checking user query to database query
$check_data = "SELECT replies FROM fallas WHERE queries LIKE '%$getMesg%'";
$run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $check_data) or die("Error");

// if user query matched to database query we'll show the reply otherwise it go to else statement
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
    //fetching replay from the database according to the user query
    $fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query);
    //storing replay to a varible which we'll send to ajax
    $replay = $fetch_data['replies'];
    echo $replay;
}else{
    echo "Sorry can't be able to understand you!";
} 

?>
```

Este es para la consulta a la base de datos alojada en phpmyadmin.
Lo que busco es como pasarlos datos cuando el usuario consulta el chat ejemplo:

- Usario: no puedo imprimir
- ChatBot: revise que su impresora este conectada a corriente.
  Que se pueda visualizar eso en una tabla es lo que no se como mandar, lo estoy trabajando todo en VSCode

Comment: Ya, bueno, no parece dificil, aunque dos cosas: 1) ¿Si ya te va dando la respuesta en cada petición que le haces al enviar texto para que quieres duplicarlas en una tabla? y 2) ¿Que has hecho al respecto para conseguirlo?  Lo digo porque me parece evidente como lo puedes conseguir tan solo mirando tu código actual, sobretodo la parte del success, donde solo tendrias que agregar más appends a la nueva tabla, al igual que cuando lo envias y haces el `$(".form").append($msg);`.  Es decir, ya casi lo tienes, pero no lo has probado ni parece que quieras aprenderlo, solo copiar y pegar la solucion

Comment: Y ese es el problema, aqui no hacemos código a medida, sino que ayudamos a comprender errores que tengais y miramos de solucionarlos, pero no hacer código a medida para que lo copies y peges en tu sitio web sin haber entendido nada. Este sitio es de programadores para programadores. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Comment: Es la primera vez que hago un proyecto asi, es como me lo estan pidiendo, y la idea de duplicar las respuestas es para que se genere una ventana a parte y se puedan ver esas respuesta, el codigo no es mio así me lo dieron y que trabajara sobre ese por lo que no se y soy novato en esto de php por lo que me cuesta trabajo comprender lo que dices del succes, lo siento por preguntar, si es asi mejor borrare todo gracias

Comment: Borra borra, aun así, como orientación, no necesitas retocar nada del código PHP, solo del código javascript y HTML, pues la respuesta del PHP ya es correcta y tan solo debes mostrarla en un nuevo elemento de tabla al igual que ya estas haciendo con `$(".form").append($msg);`... entiendo tu problema, y me sabe mal decirtelo de nuevo, pero no ayudamos con código a medida, para eso si tu no eres programador necesitas acudir a uno que te lo haga, lo siento, suerte